# Control Fire TV & Fire Stick devices via API/HTTPS

Tags: android, kotlin, television, amazon-fire-tv

I see most people use ADB to connect and control, but it is quite slow and confusing for users when having to enable "developer options"

I want it to be controllable via API like a Roku device. So does anyone know how to connect like that?

Comment: your best bet is to install the firetv app in windows and use wireshark or fiddler to capture what's going on and emulate it.  At the very least, wifi control requires a pin number handshake.

Comment: What controls do you need?